# Как пролистывать активити?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать, чтоб у юзера было две возможности навигации по приложению:

- нажатие на кнопку <kbd>Далее</kbd>
- и просто свайпом по экрану

Я так понимаю, нужно сделать все фрагментами и поместить их в контейнер (может какой-то swipe layout).

Но будет ли это нормально работать?

Comment: можете например использовать `ViewPager` с фрагментами

Comment: @metalurgus да но в таком случае я не смогу прикрепить кнопку. Будет возможность пролистывать, но я не уверен что можно будет переключать с кнопки... или можно?

Comment: `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);`, например, перелистнет на второй элемент.

Comment: `setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1)` и так до бесконечности......=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewPager` позволяет делать именно то, что вам надо.
Чтобы программно перелистнуть страницу, вы можете использовать метод `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(index, true);`, где `index` - номер страницы, на которую надо перелистнуть, а второй параметр означает, нужно ли это сделать анимированно.
Для того, чтобы переключиться на следующую страницу, можно сделать так: перелистнуть на `<текущая_страница + 1>`. Код выглядит так: `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true)`;

Comment: А не подскажите, можно ли как то ограничить возможность пролистывания в одну из сторон? Нужно дать юзеру возможность листать только вправо допустим...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, это отдельный вопрос. Задайте его, как отдельный